# Avoiding save changes before closing dialog of Acrobat Reader when viewing PDF from ArcPy of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: pdf, arcgis-pro

I often write PDF files using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 2.0 using code like:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\test.aprx")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]
lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\temp\test.pdf")
```

I view them using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, and when I close them I am asked:

> Do you want to save changes to 'test.pdf' before closing?

This means every close is two clicks instead of one, and I am not making any changes to the PDF so I am always choosing No.

I have not been able to disable this dialog being triggered from the Adobe side and am wondering whether there is a way to set a property on the PDF created by ArcGIS Pro to prevent it instead?